# JSGrid: Unable to load JSON data into grid

Tags: jquery, jsgrid

I am unable to load the JSGrid with data from the database. I tried all the answers to questions but cant seem to resolve.

```
$('#comments-grid').jsGrid({
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        pageSize: 5,
        autoload:   true,
        controller: {

            loadData: function() {
                var d = $.Deferred();
                console.log(itemid);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: URL,
                    data: {
                        itemid: itemid,
                    },
                    success: function(d){
                        console.log(d);
                    }
                }).done(function(response){
                    d.resolve(response.d);
                });

                return d.promise();
            },
        },
        fields: [
            { name: "commenttext", title: "Comment", type: "text", width: 10, align: "center", visible: true },
            { name: "created_at", title: "Created At", type: "text", width: 10, align: "center", visible: true }, 
        ]

    });
});
```

I am also getting the response back but they dont get loaded into the grid. 
[image]

My field names are as below:

```
fields: [
            { name: "commenttext", title: "Comment", type: "text", width: 10, align: "center", visible: true },
            { name: "created_at", title: "Created At", type: "text", width: 10, align: "center", visible: true }, 
        ]
```

it looks like the data is getting loaded but its blank
[image]

Can you advice what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Please post the grid data assignment code too

Comment: Hi Charlie, whats the grid data assignment? Sorry I am relatively new to this.

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `d.resolve(response);`? Also, ajax is a promise itself, so you can just return it:  `return $ajax(...)`

Comment: yes Andrei, you are right. I was trying another answer so thats why its that way.

Comment: @edcoder Your grid code

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks, I've updated my question with the entire grid code.

Comment: can you try this un your json done `d.resolve(jQuery.parseJSON(response.d));`

Comment: Hi Alejandro, its giving me this error, when I try that.  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data[Learn More]

Answer (score 0):

solved: My 'name' field was not matching the values of my SQL output. The SQL return values need to match the field names.